# Formula of currentTimeMillis() in java?

Tags: java, math, time

To my knowledge, `System.currentTimeMillis()/1000` can show the current time in seconds since

> 1970-1-1 00:00:00 (YY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss)

For example

> 2013-10-12 21:30:00 (YY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss)

= **13815846XX (not sure whats X for)**

I was wondering how to calculate it. Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: What? Are you trying to format the milliseconds as a date string?

Comment: I prefer how to cal that time out. But yes

Comment: Do you meant to ask, how a difference between 2 dates is converted into milliseconds?!

Comment: Voting to close as unclear what you are asking here.

Comment: I can't quite see what you're asking. It seems that you've answered it yourself. Why specifically ask about the last two digits in "*13815846XX (not sure whats X for)*"? Also, not that this number is the number of seconds since 1/1/1970 midnight *in UTC*. You're not saying in which time zone you are, but 13815846XX (any value of XX) would put you in UTC+8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` just returns the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (January 1st 1970, midnight UTC), as a `long`.

Converting that value into a string is normally the job of something like [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), via [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) and [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html). Alternatively, look at [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) for a nicer date/time API.

If you want to *start* with a date and get the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch, you'd use `Calendar`, set the appropriate fields and then use `Calendar.getTimeInMillis()`. (Or again, use Joda Time.) Be careful about time zone interactions.

You can use [Epoch Converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/) to check your computations.

A value such as 1381584600 is most likely to be a Unix timestamp, which is the number of *seconds* (not milliseconds) since the Unix epoch - hence the division by 1000 that you mention.

If this doesn't tell you what you need, please ask a more precise question.

Comment: `13815846XX` is most likely a UNIX timestamp.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Yes, possibly. The question is unclear at the moment. I've added a mention of that into the answer.

Comment: Pretty sure since `13815846XX` with any 2 last digits map to the date `2013-10-12`, but yes, not the clearest question :)